# Add a '1' to a cell if a value is between two times in Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have imported an Excel file into a data frame that has a column called 'Opened' which has a date and time when something was opened.

I want to have a new column labeled '07:01 - 09:00' and every row that has an opened time in between that time I want to add a '1' on the same row in the column.

So far I have this

```
Opened                            
2020-04-14 14:45:58 
2020-04-07 17:53:49 
2020-04-07 07:10:14 
2020-04-06 23:11:13
```

What I want is

```
Opened                07:01 - 09:00              
2020-04-14 14:45:58 
2020-04-07 17:53:49 
2020-04-07 07:10:14         1
2020-04-06 23:11:13
```

So the cells that don't contain a time between what's specified in the column won't get a '1' in the cell.

Ones that do will.

Some code

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('opened.xlsx')
fmt = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

data['Opened'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Opened'],
                                     format=fmt,
                                     errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html) for times and then test by [`numpy.in1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html?highlight=in1d#numpy.in1d) for test positions:

```
idx = df.set_index('Opened').index.indexer_between_time('07:01','09:00')

#if default index RangeIndex
#df['07:01 - 09:00'] = df.index.isin(idx).astype(int)
#any index
df['07:01 - 09:00'] = np.in1d(np.arange(len(df)), idx).astype(int)
print (df)
               Opened  07:01 - 09:00
0 2020-04-14 14:45:58              0
1 2020-04-07 17:53:49              0
2 2020-04-07 07:10:14              1
3 2020-04-06 23:11:13              0
```

Or if need empty values (mixed data in output, so possible problem in next processing) is possible use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['07:01 - 09:00'] = np.where(np.in1d(np.arange(len(df)), idx), 1, '')
print (df)
               Opened 07:01 - 09:00
0 2020-04-14 14:45:58              
1 2020-04-07 17:53:49              
2 2020-04-07 07:10:14             1
3 2020-04-06 23:11:13
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I've not thought about using Numpy!

Answer (score 3):

set the date as the index, and use pandas [between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) to get ur values :

```
df = df.set_index('Opened')

df.loc[df.between_time('07:01','09:00').index, '07:01 - 09:00'] = 1


                      07:01 - 09:00
Opened  
2020-04-14 14:45:58          NaN
2020-04-07 17:53:49          NaN
2020-04-07 07:10:14          1
2020-04-06 23:11:13          NaN
```